# Python extracting string

Tags: python, pandas, string, extract

I have a dataframe where one of the columns which is in string format looks like this

```
    filename
 0  Machine02-2022-01-28_00-21-45.blf.424
 1  Machine02-2022-01-28_00-21-45.blf.425
 2  Machine02-2022-01-28_00-21-45.blf.426
 3  Machine02-2022-01-28_00-21-45.blf.427
 4  Machine02-2022-01-28_00-21-45.blf.428
```

I want my column to look like this

```
      filename
 0    2022-01-28 00-21-45 424
 1    2022-01-28 00-21-45 425
 2    2022-01-28 00-21-45 426
 3    2022-01-28 00-21-45 427
 4    2022-01-28 00-21-45 428
```

I tried this code

```
df['filename'] = df['filename'].str.extract(r"(\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})_(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}).*\.(\d+)", r"\1 \2 \3")
```

I am getting this error, unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'.
Can anyone please tell me where I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Not sure why you're getting this error but here is what it means: `&` is the so-called "bit-wise and operator" which applies "AND" bit by bit (thus the name). Python converts ints to binary on the fly for thisoperator, but for strings this is not possible. You get a similar error when you try `+` a int and string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please try this:

```
df['filename'] = df['filename'].str.split('-',1).apply(lambda x:' '.join(x[1].split('_')).replace('.blf.',' '))
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `str.replace` and add `.*-` to remove strings like `Machine02-`:

```
df['filename'] = df['filename'].str.replace(r".*-(\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})_(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}).*\.(\d+)", r"\1 \2 \3")
print(df)

# Output
                  filename
0  2022-01-28 00-21-45 424
1  2022-01-28 00-21-45 425
2  2022-01-28 00-21-45 426
3  2022-01-28 00-21-45 427
4  2022-01-28 00-21-45 428
```

Comment: I tried this, it didn't worked

Comment: I don't understand, it seems to work with your example, no?

Comment: Its not working with  my example

Comment: @Vinay_S this does exactly what you want, as advertised, I have tried it out. What error are you facing?

Comment: I am not getting error, I am getting the output same as input

Comment: It's really strange. Do you have any leading or trailing space in your data?

Comment: @Corralien Thanks for this input. I had leading space, that's why it was not working. Now its working. Thanks once again

Answer (score 4):

Use replace

```
df['filename']=df['filename'].str.replace('Machine|\.blf\.',' ',regex=True).str.strip().str.replace('^\d+\-','',regex=True)



 filename
0  2022-01-28_00-21-45 424
1  2022-01-28_00-21-45 425
2  2022-01-28_00-21-45 426
3  2022-01-28_00-21-45 427
4  2022-01-28_00-21-45 428
```

or

Extract values between e02 and .blf

```
df['filename']=df['filename'].str.extract('((?<=[e02])[\w|\-]+(?=[.blf]))')



    filename
0  02-2022-01-28_00-21-45
1  02-2022-01-28_00-21-45
2  02-2022-01-28_00-21-45
3  02-2022-01-28_00-21-45
4  02-2022-01-28_00-21-45
```

Comment: I think you missed the suffix (424, 425, 426, ...)

Answer (score 1):

Regex are nice, but sometimes is easier and more readable to make a replace, if the arguments won't ever change:

```
df['filename'] = df['filename'].str.replace('Machine02-','',regex=False)
df['filename'] = df['filename'].str.replace('.blf.',' ',regex=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I am currently using it and it will work only if string has 'Machine02-' . Sometimes I may have random names like M2, Mach2, etc. I have a huge data and I can't keep looking like that. So I am trying another method which I explained in question